# how to create an umbraco site programatically

Tags: model-view-controller, umbraco

how to create an umbraco site programatically? the following url creates a  basic site but does not involve any coding. How do we create a site through coding in visual studio by installing umbraco through nuget? Does anyone know any tutorials to start creating a site through coding?

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Tutorials/Creating-Basic-Site/Getting-Started

Answer (score 3):

My standard approach is to create a blank ASP.Net website, no need to specify MVC or anything; then in the new project just grab the UmbracoCMS NuGet Package, build and run - you'll be presented with the Installer screen the first time through.

I also create a separate project - something lime "MyWebsite.Code" and use NuGet to install the UmbracoCMS.Core package to get the dlls and their dependencies; that way I can separate out the business logic, controllers for views, models, etc.

Comment: Oh that's smart to do the UmbraocCMS.Core in another project. I did it all in one poject for my first because UmbracoCMS nuget instlaled core as a dependancy. :(

Comment: This is pretty much my approach too for most Umbraco sites!